How Do I Use Okta Groups with Google's Workforce Identity Federation
So I have an Okta app, we'll call it Test App, that I am using for OIDC with Google Workforce Identity Federation. I'm attempting to use Okta groups as a principal set within GCP:IAM. This works correctly whenever I use an attribute/assertion but I'm having no luck with Okta groups. Whenever I select the Test App from the Okta Dashboard, I have no errors, yet I cannot see anything within GCP. It shows "No Organization" which leads me to believe it is authenticating but the role is not being successfully applied.
I've went into the Test App -> Sign On within Okta and enabled a groups claim filter under the OpenID Connect ID Token section. I have the "Groups claim type" set to "Filter" and "Groups claim filter" set to "groups matches regex .*". I have the group (Testing Group) assigned to the app within Okta. Under the Test App -> Okta API Scopes tab I have okta.groups.read granted.
For clarity, here's the workforce pool infrastructure in Terraform:
resource "google_iam_workforce_pool_provider" "okta_workforce_provider" {
   workforce_pool_id = test-pool
   location          = global
   provider_id       = okta
   attribute_mapping = {
      "google.subject"       = "assertion.name"
      "google.groups"        = "assertion.groups"
      "attribute.department" = "assertion.department"
      "attribute.email"      = "assertion.email"
   }

   oidc {
      client_id = var.client_id
      client_secret {
         value {
            plain_text = var.secret
         }
      }
      issuer_url = "https://my.test.org"
      web_sso_config {
         assertion_claims_behavior = "MERGE_USER_INFO_OVER_ID_TOKEN_CLAIMS"
         response_type             = "CODE"
      }
   }
}

I've tested this and it works:
resource "google_organization_iam_member" "good_test_attribute" {
   member = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${google_iam_workforce_pool.test-pool.name}/attribute.department/Testing Department"
   org_id = "111111111"
   role   = "roles/browser"
}

However I need this and it does not work:
resource "google_organization_iam_member" "bad_test_group" {
   member = "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${google_iam_workforce_pool.test-pool.name}/group/Testing Group"
   org_id = "111111111"
   role   = "roles/browser"
}

I've done enough document diving this week that SeaWorld has been calling and is offering me an exhibit. Seriously though- I'm starting to draw a blank and my attempts at trial/error are unsuccessful. I'm almost tempted to try a SAML integration instead. Please help me Stack Overflow.. you're my only hope!
